# I want to deploy my node.js website to domain name with laptop as server

Tags: node.js, deployment, localhost, web-deployment, host

I purchased a domain name and developed a node app on local host now I want to deploy it to my domain name. And I don't want hosting I want my laptop work as a Server for my node app on my Domain name What should I do?

**App : NodeJs ExpressJs 

Laptop : Ubuntu Server 

Domain From : BigRock**

Comment: This question probably doesn't belong in stackoverflow because this is really a network configuration problem, not so much a programming problem.  Assuming your laptop is on your home network, do you have a static (non-changing) IP address for your home?

Comment: No I don't have static ip address what should I do?

Comment: I will give you a few hints here, but your question doesn't really belong here.  Find and configure a dynamic DNS service for your external IP address (a premium router will have a service like that built in, but there are others you can use). Then, open a hole in your router firewall to port forward the one desired port (likely port 80) so that traffic arriving at the outside of your router on that port will be forwarded to your laptop computer inside your network, then make absolutely sure your laptop server isn't vulnerable to any attacks via that port because people will try to attack.

Comment: Okay Thank you so much for the help 